# Android sql creating database once

Tags: java, android, sql, database

I want to create the database and all the data ONCE and update some data maybe later when needed. Throughout most of the tutorials I have read, they use two classes: one that extends SQLiteOpenHelper and another to simplify manipulating data. For example:

```
public class EventsData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "events.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID + " INT, " + TITLE + " TEXT, " + UNLOCK + " INT)";
private static final String DATABASE_UPGRADE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

public EventsData(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_UPGRADE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

```
public class DataHelper {

private static final String[] FROM = {ID, TITLE, UNLOCK};
//private static final String ORDER_BY = UNLOCK + " DESC";

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private EventsData eventsData;

public DataHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    eventsData = new EventsData(this.context);
}

public void addEvent(int id, String name, int unlocked) {
    db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(ID, id);
    cv.put(TITLE, name);
    cv.put(UNLOCK, unlocked);
    db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}

public void updateEvent(int id, String name, int unlocked) {
    db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(ID, id);
    cv.put(TITLE, name);
    cv.put(UNLOCK, unlocked);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, ID + "=" + id, null);
}

public Cursor getEvent() {
    db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}

public StringBuilder showEvent(Cursor cursor) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cursor.getString(0);
        String title = cursor.getString(1);
        String unlock = cursor.getString(2);
        sb.append(id).append(": ");
        sb.append(unlock).append(": ");
        sb.append(title).append("\n");
    }
    return sb;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
}
```

}

In my main activity, I create an instance of DataHelper and call addEvent() to create and add data to the database. But everytime the application starts, it's going to "reset" all the data even if I were to call updateEvent().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty unclear what you want. Either you want to run the commands once when the db is created, or you want to run the more often. If you want to run them only on creation, but them in oncreate. If you want to run them some other amount of times, put them somewhere else. Right now I have no idea what you're trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: Just wanted to create the database once. I wanted to use the DataHelper class I created to simplify things when it comes to updating data.

Comment: Your databaseHelper's onCreate method should only be called if the database isn't created. So It's not clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 3):

You can use DBVersion to control this behaviour.

If you are extending SQLiteOpenHelper, you can pass DBVersion in the constructor. 
code snippet as follows.

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public MyDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

See attribute version doco http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29

Any code that has to executed for the first time (only) needs to be added in onCreate() method. To control db changes subsequently (eg. alter table, update table etc) should be handled in onUpdate.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions you can override in an SQLiteOpenHelper which are onCreate() and onUpgrade(). onCreate() is called if the database and tables do not exist on the device and then, creates the file for you. onUpgrade() is called if you pass a different version number to the helper in the constructor. This is useful if you need to make vital changes to your database on the device only once.

```
private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

                        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name, int version) {
                            super(context, name, null, version);
                        }            

                        @Override
                        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                            try {
                                //Create tables here
                                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + table_name + args);
                            } catch(SQLException e) {
                                //Database error
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                            //This will be called if your database version ever changes
                            this.onCreate(db);
                        }
}
```

Hopefully this helps you out.